# Add local package in miniconda

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, gurobi, miniconda

I have a local python package. setup.py script of the package puts it in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ but when I import the package it fails. I guess this is because I am using miniconda. Any ideas on how to gel it with miniconda?